# pycurl READFUNCTION callback not called when using FORM_FILE

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I'm sending a file using HTTPPOST and FORM_FILE and I'd like to register to the READFUNCTION callback in order to abort the transfer in certain cases (low network coverage).

Here is a sample of my code:

```
self.curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
self.curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPOST, [
    ('file', (
        pycurl.FORM_FILE, img_path,
    )),
])
filesize = os.path.getsize(img_path)
self.curl.setopt(pycurl.INFILESIZE, filesize)
self.curl.setopt(pycurl.READFUNCTION, self.FileReader(img_path,         self).read_callback)

self.curl.perform()
```

The file is correctly sent but the callback is not called.

Note: the callback is called if I send the file with POST, but I need http.

Comment: You might want to read the libcurl [curl_formadd docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html) which then explains that `FORM_FILE` doesn't read from the callback. You need `FORM_STREAM` for that. If pycurl supports it.

Comment: Sadly, it does not seem to support it. Is there a workaround ?